# Displaying Arraylist from another method

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, methods, indexing

My problem that Im having here is that I want to output a lettergrade for three student scores on a separate file in the format:

```
name1   score1
name2   score2
name3    score3
```

with tabs in between the score and names.

The problem I'm faced with here is if you scroll down to my toString2 method, I will run my program and it should take in the three scores and output the correct letter grades according to my calculations. Instead my programs goes into an uncontrolled loop and ends with a []. How can i fix this?

```
 package file;

 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class ReadData2 
{
ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Double> score  = new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<String> lettergrade = new ArrayList<String>();
double mean;
double std;

public ReadData2()
{
    mean= 0;
    std=0;
}
public  void readData(File file) throws FileNotFoundException 
{
    //File file = new File("data.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    int l = 0;


    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) { 
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        String [] words = line.split("\t"); 
        name.add(words[0]); 
        score.add(Double.parseDouble(words[1]));
    }
}

public String toString()
{

    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    for(String n: name)
    {
        out.append(n);
        out.append("\n");

    }
    for(double n: score)
    {
        out.append(n);
        out.append("\n");   
    }
    return out.toString();      
}   

public double fndMean()
{
    double mean  = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    for(Double n: score)
    {
        sum= sum+n; 
    }
    mean= sum/score.size();
    return mean;
}

public double fndStandard()
{
    double sumOfDifferences = 0;
    double mean = fndMean();
    for(Double n: score)
    {
        sumOfDifferences += Math.pow((n- mean),2);  
    }
    double temp = sumOfDifferences/ score.size();
    return Math.sqrt(temp);
}
public  ArrayList<String>  toString2(File file) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    StringBuilder grades = new StringBuilder();
    double mean1 = fndMean();
    double std1 = fndStandard();

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    int l = 0;

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) { 
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        String [] words = line.split("\t"); 
        name.add(words[0]); 
        score.add(Double.parseDouble(words[1]));

        for(double n: score)
        {
            grades.append(n);
            grades.append("\n");    
        }


        for(int i = 0; i < ((score.size())) && i < name.size(); i++)
        {
            if(mean1 +std1 < score.get(i))
            {
                System.out.println("A");
            }
            else if( (score.get(i) >= mean1+(std1/3)) &&  (mean1 +std1)> score.get(i))
            {
                System.out.println("B");
            }
            else if( (score.get(i) >= mean1-(std1/3)) &&  (mean1 +(std1/3))> score.get(i))
            {
                System.out.println("C");

            }
            else if( (score.get(i) >= mean1-(std1)) &&  (mean -(std1/3))> score.get(i))
            {
                System.out.println("D");
            }   
            else if(mean1 - std1 > score.get(i))
            {
                System.out.println("F");
            }

        }
    }
    return lettergrade;
}
}
```

Comment: Could you try to format your code better? Preferably use an IDE to auto-format.

Comment: alright i just did

Comment: Thanks, so where is the error? Have you used a debugger?

Comment: so theres not error, it's just my output is going into an uncontrolled loop. There are only three scores however it is outputting many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Instead my programs goes into an uncontrolled loop and ends with a
>   []. How can i fix this?

You are getting an empty [] because you are not really modifying your "lettergrade" array. You are simply printing the grade to the console, not really adding it to the array. Instead of or besides the sysout statements, you need to add the grades to the arrays. E.g.

`lettergrade.add("B");`

Comment: When i tried that i get [F, C, A, F, F, C, A, F, C, F, C, A, F, C, A]

Comment: @JustAJAVAGUY, what was your input and what is your expected output?

Comment: name1   score1
name2   score2
name3    score3      // myinput from a txt file and my output should display letter grades according to score1-score3

Comment: also they shouldnt be in square brackets, just descending similar to a column